# How to call javascript validate function before form submit on an ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here is my validate() function, returns either true or false.
My problen is i want to call ajax submit form code only if validate() returns true, otherwise it will show the alert with error messages for not valid data and stay in page Without submitting the form , without using ajax I know that i can use if true return document.form2.submit();but in my case it doesn't work, Please help!

Ajax Code :

```
$("#form2").submit(function(){

var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: "addv.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    success: function (data) {
        $('.fv').html(data).hide().fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
    },
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
}); 

return false;
});
```

javascript function :

```
function validate()
{
    var m=document.getElementById("mat").value;
    var c=document.getElementById("kilo").value;
    var v=true;
    if(!isNaN(m))
        {
          alert("matricule  doit etre une chaine !");
          document.getElementById("mat").value=null;
          v=false;
        }
    if(isNaN(c))
        {
          alert("kilométrage doit etre un entier !");
          document.getElementById("kilo").value=null;  
          v=false;
        }
       return v;
}
```

Form :

```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form2" id="form2">
         <label >Matricule</label></br>
         <input type="text" name="mat"></br>
         <label>kilométrage</label></br>
         <input type="text" name="kilo"></br>
         <label>Marque</label>  </br>
         <select name="mar" id="mar">
          <?php  
            while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($req1))
            {
              echo "<option> $res[0] </option>";
            }
          ?>    
         </select>
         <label>Propriétaire Cin</label>  </br>
         <select name="pro" id="prop" onchange=fn()>
          <?php  
            while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($req2))
            {
              echo "<option> $res[0] </option>";
            }
          ?> 
           </select>
         <label>Nom et Prénom</label>  </br>
         <input type="text" disabled id="propr"></br>
         <label>Photo</label>  </br></br>
         <input type="file" name="img" id="img"style="color:red;"></br></br>
         <input type="submit" value="Ajouter">
         <b><p class="fv" style="color:red" align="center"></p></b>
 </form>
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, do with it what you want, but I noticed you are using jquery here and I have found this validation lib <http://jqueryvalidation.org/ > to be a great tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [preventDefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to prevent submit of form. And use condition if validate returns true then use Ajax other case show alert

```
$("#form2").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if(validate()){

    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
      url: "addv.php",
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      success: function (data) {
        $('.fv').html(data).hide().fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
      },
      contentType: false,
      processData: false
    });     
  } else {
   alert('error');
  }
});
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you so much :) just there are a Note i can't understand it, I deleted alert('error') code now is : else{ } and without calling validate(); messages errors appear, knowing that else block doesn't contain anything !!

Comment: There are two alerts inside validate function.

Comment: validate function can return error message, or array of messages instead of boolean, and if it is empty you can create Ajax request but if not show them.

Comment: Also take a look at form validation attributes, it also gives good solution for user friendly form validation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation

Comment: Great! Thank you so much & have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'my_action',
    dataType: 'script',
    beforeSend : function(xhr, opts){
        if(!validate()) //just an example
        {
            xhr.abort();
        }
    },
    complete: function(){
        console.log('DONE');
    }
});
```

You can check if your data is valid or not and based on it abort ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, when I submit my forms via ajax I tend not to use submit button.

```
<input type="submit" value="Ajouter">
```

to

```
<input type="button" id="process_form" value="Ajouter">
```

then you can add some JS functions like

```
$('#process_form').click ( function (e) {
  if(validate){
    // AJAX HERE
  }else{
    // return errors
  }
});
```

That should get you moving in the right direction. In your case the form won't submit because you have not supplied a method nor an action. When using Ajax these aren't required though.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$("#userFrm input,#userFrm  select").each(function(index, value){
                if(value.checkValidity()==false){
                alert("error message");
                return false
            }
        });
// AJAX HERE
```